# Using 'ctex' and 'translations' packages together

Tags: babel, chinese, ctex, translations

I have numerous documents in English which will be translated into Chinese. I use *ctex* package for Chinese typesetting and *XeLaTeX* for compiling. There are some strings repeating throughout the document (note, attention, feedback, etc.) which I would like to have translated into Chinese automatically using the *translations* package.

I check if *ctex* is loaded with `\IfPackageLoaded`, and then use `\selectlanguage{chinese}`.

MWE:

mypreamble.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}[test]

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\babelprovide{chinese}
\usepackage{translations}

\DeclareLanguage{chinese}

\newcommand*\location{\GetTranslation{mycountry}}

% translations for 'mycountry':
\DeclareTranslationFallback {mycountry}{Default}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{mycountry}{Country}
\DeclareTranslation{chinese} {mycountry}{国家}

% code required for checking if ctex is loaded
\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[3]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mypreamble}

% comment out for English, uncomment for Chinese
\usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}

\IfPackageLoaded{ctex}{\selectlanguage{chinese}}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{Intro}
\location

\end{document}
```

Below is what I want and get **if I do not add babel** (which is required by *translations*). However, it also gives me an **error** `Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language chinese yet`.

[image]

**If I add babel** by uncommenting the two strings in preamble, the error disappears; but then *babel* messes up with *ctex*'s translation of standard strings (Contents, List of Tables, etc.) into Chinese:

[image]

**Any help to resolve this dilemma will be very much appreciated!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like you would need

```latex
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{chinese}
```

to avoid the error. However `babel-zh.ini` (as well as other Chinese locales, e.g. `babel-zh-Hant-HK.ini`, `babel-zh-Hans.ini` etc) doesn't define keys in the `[captions]` section, so `\chinesecontentsname`, `\chineselisttablename` etc are undefined. AFAIK there isn't a way for `babel` to automatically go look up these defined terms from `ctex`.

(In TL 2020 `babel-ja.ini` and `babel-ko.ini` *do* define key-value pairs in `[captions]`, so you would not have this problem if you were working with `\babel[import]{japanese}` or `\babel[import]{korean}`. But still not the case for `babel-zh.ini` in TL2020.)

You can define these commands yourself in your main.tex or mypreamble.sty:

```latex
\renewcommand{\chinesecontentsname}{目录}
\renewcommand{\chineselisttablename}{表格}
```

Or if you prefer, you can make a copy of `babel-zh.ini` (it's in `/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/zh/`), rename it to `babel-zh-myownhacks.ini`, and edit the `[captions]` section:

```
[captions]
preface = 前言
ref = 参考文献
abstract = 摘要
...
```

and then load it in your .tex/.sty via

```latex
\babelprovide[import=zh-myownhacks]{chinese}
```

Comment: A copy of `babel-zh.ini` worked without a hitch. Added it to a subfolder as suggested [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I%20have%20a%20lot%20of%20.cls,%20.sty,%20.bst%20files,%20and%20I%20want%20to%20put%20them%20in%20a%20folder%20to%20keep%20my%20project%20uncluttered.%20But%20my%20project%20is%20not%20finding%20them%20to%20compile%20correctly) to avoid cluttering my root directory. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot find an option to import my custom .ini file from a different directory. Not sure how to add a path to it. Does anybody know how to do it?